# Conditionally render 404 route with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my most parent component `App` I implemented my route like this:

```
<GetCustomerData />
<Switch>
    <Route path="/dashboard/:customerID" component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

`GetCustomerData` gets the customer data as an array of JSON payload (including the customer ID). We navigate to `Dashboard` component for a specific customer with their corresponding ID.

I want to setup a route which basically throws a 404 component if the customer ID we pass in the URL doesn't exist in the JSON payload in `GetCustomerData`.

I've seen some tutorials that say to do something like:

```
 <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
```

But this doesn't really check for the `customerID` param in the url. How do I implement this?

EDIT:
In my main component I have Browser route configured in this way:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="main">
            <App />
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    ,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First setup a 404 route

```
<Route path="/error" component={NotFound} />
```

Then store your `GetCustomerData`data in an array in state. It is unclear where the data comes from or how you can manipulate it from your example. If getting the data into the component state is a problem create a separate question.

If you are pulling the id from the URL then use the route parameter in props to get your customer id `this.props.match.params.customerID`

Once you have the data and the id handy then you can run a check in your render method.

```
if (this.state.data.includes(this.props.match.params.customerID)){
 return <whatYouExpectedToReturn/>
}else{
 return <Redirect to='/error'/>;
}
```

Comment: The data payload (coming from an API call) is stored in `GetCustomerData`. Since the if-check is done inside `App`, do you think its a good idea to send the payload to `App` from `GetCustomerData` and then do the check?

Comment: It depends on where you want to redirect from. I would do this inside the Dashboard component since that is the only place the url will have the customer Id in it.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm updating the original post to give you a better idea of where the App component sits.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of your file structure would be more helpful, the tree of files usually on the left of your code editor.

Comment: To elaborate, you should have a file with your `Dashboard` component. That's the one you refrenced in your dashboard route. Then you should have a file for your `NotFound` component. That's the one you refrenced in your 404 route. Then you have a router file with all your routes (I think you are calling it main). I'm suggesting you put the if-then block I wrote out in the render method in your Dashboard component, since that is where you want to redirect from.

Comment: The complication would be passing your JSON payload into the dashboard component as a prop. Since we know nothing about your data or where it's coming from, I suggest you open a new question for that because that is a different problem. My answer should clarify the question you asked, which is how to render a 404 route with your setup. You pop a redirect component in the component you want to redirect from.